# Where do I manage email alerts sent for CLoud Logging Sink Errors?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have a Google Cloud Logging Sink configured to export from Logging to BigQuery.

I am receiving emails to the wrong email address, but I can't find where to manage/update these notification emails. Where do I do this?

I've tried:

- https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#edit-delete-channel
- Editing the Sink > no options to manage alerts

Comment: Have a look at [email notificagtions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/troubleshoot#view-errors-email). I was unaware of this until you asked this question so, thanks!

Comment: thanks but no emails are listed in that page :/

Comment: The page says "If there aren't any Technical Essential Contacts configured for a resource, then users listed as IAM Project Owner roles/owner for the resource receive the email notification."

Comment: oh i missed that line - thanks! want to leave an answer i can accept?

Comment: Added an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [email notifications](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/troubleshoot#view-errors-email).

The page says:

> If there aren't any Technical Essential Contacts configured for a resource, then users listed as IAM Project Owner roles/owner for the resource receive the email notification.

Comment: I've added one email, but still receiving those log sink errors to multiple other ones :(

Comment: This is more of a support question. I encourage you to contact Google directly and have Google Support help you resolve this. Good luck!